# Dexguard lib environment check in mobile failing for MI, Appo, Yureka devices

Tags: android, dexguard, rooted-device

I have implemented dexguard in my project. When I run an environment check, some devices work fine and pass the check. However in MI, Appo, Yureka devices, the check is returning it that the device is rooted. I am not able to understand why those this happen.

Please help me to figure out this issue.

Comment: Rephrased the question and fixed grammatical mistakes.

Comment: I also facing same issue when using dexguard environment check. All MI device is showing as rooted. Have you got any solution @user3069590

Comment: no still now i didn't get solution manually we are checking user from server side

Answer (score 0):

False positives in `DexGuard` and other root detection libraries are often down to certain binary checks. The **`"su"`** binary and the **`"busybox"`** binaries are sometimes found on the ROM of certain manufacturers phones. Try the `RootBeer` library which can be added as a maven dependency.

https://github.com/scottyab/rootbeer